# Double precision - Max value

Tags: c, double

I have a pretty silly question on double precision. I have read that a double (in C for example) is represented on 64 bits, but I have also read that the maximum value that can be represented by a double is approximately 10^308. How can 10^308 be represented with only 64 bits?

Comment: You might want to read about the [IEEE floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: ... Pretty much the same as this *huge* number can be expressed with only the 6 characters `10^308`.

Comment: There is also infinity for IEEE floating points (which I'd say is the maximum value). How can _that_ be represented? ;)

Comment: Detail: `DBL_MAX` is the maximum _finite_ `double` - often about 1.8e308.  Many, (most), systems also allow an "infinity" which is greater than `DBL_MAX` and, of course, does not take infinite bits to represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not hold the 308 digits of the 10^308 number. The double precision number holds the exponent and a limited number of digits.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point (english) http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 (french) for a detailed description of floating points encoding in memory.

Comment: Did you mean to link [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)? :-)

Comment: Yes sorry. Got the french version.

Answer (score 1):

According to C standard, there are three floating point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`, and the value representation of all floating-point types are **implementation defined**.

Most compilers however do follow the binary64 format, as specified by the IEEE 754 standard.

This format has:

- 1 sign bit
- 11 bits for exponent
- 52 bits for mantissa

To find the largest value `double` can hold, you should check the `DBL_MAX` defined in the header `<float.h>`. It will be approximately 1.8 × 10<sup>308</sup> for implementations using binary64 IEEE 754 standard.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exponent in the bit pattern of the 64 bits floating point IEEE numbers. In Python I compute the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 2**(-52) == np.finfo(np.float64).eps
True
>>> np.finfo(np.float64).max
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> (2-2**(-52)) * 2**(2**10-1)
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> (2-2**(-52)) * 2**(2**10-1) == np.finfo(np.float64).max
True
```

So it is a bit more than 10^308. The "2**(2**10-1)" is the exponent part. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format